# An efficient way to write MySql query that has duplicate column names

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a reasonably straightforward MySQL query as follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM post INNER JOIN comment ON post.post_id = comment.post_id
WHERE post.host = 99999
ORDER BY post.post_id
```

My problem is that some of my column names are common to both the post and comment table.  In the result, the column name appears only once, and its values are taken from the last table in the query (ie. the comment table).

I realise that I could explicitly list each column name in the `SELECT` part of the query, and use aliases to differentiate between duplicate column names, but there are a lot of columns in each table and it would be messy.

Is there a more efficient way to go about it?

Comment: If you are using `INNER JOIN` on similar columns you may as well use `USING` syntax.

Comment: listing column names i always a good approach, it gives a hint to MySQL optimizer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just use aliases for those columns that are alike and then * for the rest:

```
SELECT post.post_id, comment.post_id as comment_post_id, *
FROM ...
```

I don't think there is a better approach.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Listing column names is always a better approach as long as it is feasible, it may give some hint to the MySQL optimizer.

Additionally, I would use Using syntax when the Join is done on similar column name.

```
SELECT x.x1, x.x2 ... , y.x1, y.x2 ... 
FROM post as x 
INNER JOIN comment as y 
USING post_id
WHERE ...
```

Answer (score -1):

You can select all the column from both the table.Just give an alias to the both table name and the use alias.* after select statement.

Then it will select all the column from the table.

Example:

```
SELECT pst.*,cmt.* from post pst INNER JOIN comment cmt
FROM ...
```